# Performance of MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE over small file

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm loading a small data file which consists around 1K rows into a MyISAM table

```
{
id INT(8), 
text TEXT(or VARCHAR(1000))
}
```

The cost is around 2 seconds for LOAD DATA INFILE. I've seen MySQL could load more than 10K rows per second in average when loading large files. And I roughly know there are cost such as open/close tables. Can someone help me know what exactly happen in this 2 seconds and is it possible to optimize it under seconds as my program is running in a time critical environment. Thanks.

Somebody asked a similar question here
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?144,558753,558753.
Looks like it has not been well answered yet.

Scenario Description

The whole MySQL setup is for some academic projects, which has around 300G databases for various projects. Most of these databases are in MyISAM engine if not ALL. These databases contains imported dumps, and processed intermediate tables in experiments. There are delete and update operations on these tables, but now they are all idle. I have a project which generate some result tuples that are inserted into a table in one of the databases. The table is initialized to be empty. The schema is very simple which contains only two columns as I pasted.  Now if I set the ENGINE=MyISAM, it always takes 2s to insert 1-1K row, however, if I switch to ENGINE=INNODB, it becomes 0.01s. I installed a new MySQL in the other machine, create the table with ENGINE=MyISAM, and  insert the same number of rows, it only takes 0.01s.

Comment: which is it - text or varchar ?

Comment: both are the same, I tried it on a new installed MySQL, it is quite fast in 0.015s. The old MySQL which have been running long hosting x00G data may have some problems affect this..

Answer (score 0):

At 1k rows, you may find that multi-inserts are faster.  Some benchmarking should help.  This should be helpful as well:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb.html

Comment: Actually, I have tried INSERT INTO table with multiple values, the performance is almost the same around 2 seconds. The link you send is about optimizing INNODB, will that also work on MyISAM? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using MyISAM tables, this link would be more useful:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html

Comment: I tried load data infile of 1K rows on a new install MySQL server, it takes only 0.015 seconds. I think it might due to slow down of old MySQL for some reason.

Comment: I still have not solved the problem. MySQL even takes 2s to load just one row. BTW, the database contains over several hundred G data, would that be a problem?

Comment: I would guess it's the size of your tables, especially since the "new" server is really fast. Can you archive some of the older data away?  Partitions might be useful as well: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html

Comment: Many thanks for your patience. I did not archive any data. Today I tried to use INNODB engine for the same table, the insert takes only 0.01s. The MyISAM engine still takes 2s. I do not know how this happen. And all other 300G tables are stored in MyISAM, would that leads to a possible explanation?

Comment: Did you test InnoDB with 300GB of data, or an empty table?  Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`, please?  Can you describe how the database is used?  Do you ever update or delete the rows, or just insert new rows?  Are there many reads, or mostly just writes?  I suggest you setup a test database on a different server where you can measure performance of various configurations.  Use real data if you can, or create random data of the right form and size.

Comment: The description is too long, so I edit the original question. I tried to make it as clearly as possible. I also have tried clear query and log.

Comment: I wonder if listing the tables is taking the time.  How many tables do you have?  Are the inserts slow from the command line too?  Does your application open a new connection each time?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm not sure by listing the tables you mean all tables in MySQL or this database. For this MySQL we might have hundreds of tables. For this table it is the only one in test.test. The inserts is always taking 2s for even loading a single row. There is no application yet. Thanks.